# Constant bluescreens upon Windows 7 login

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, bsod

I'm running a Lenovo ThinkPad E540, which dual boots into Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04. The computer itself is maybe 2.5 years old, and I'm having some problems with the Windows installation. When I boot into Windows, the computer bluescreens after I sign in.

I've been having problems with Windows for a while already. Maybe about a year back, I had to reinstall my Windows, because it did the same thing. The clean install fixed things for a while, but not long after, I began getting intermittent bluescreens at login and waking up from suspension. The reason of the bluescreens changes pretty much every time.

The curious thing is that I have zero problems when I'm running Ubuntu. That makes me believe that if it is a hardware problem, it has to do with the Windows partition of the HD. I've ran the **Disk utility** that comes with Ubuntu, but it found no problems with the HD.

I'm guessing that reinstalling Windows might help with the problem, but due to my previous experience of this not actually fixing the problem, I'm not sure I want to go through that hassle again. Any ideas what the problem could be about? I'm pretty sure I can find the Windows bluescreen system dumps, if that would be of any help.

EDIT: Below is the dump from BlueScreenView. I took it by running BlueScreenView on Ubuntu via Wine. I included all 2017 dumps, there are many different error messages in there.

```
==================================================
Dump File         : 031517-24570-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 15.3.2017 6:49:37
Bug Check String  : BAD_POOL_CALLER
Bug Check Code    : 0x000000c2
Parameter 1       : 00000000`00000007
Parameter 2       : 00000000`0000109b
Parameter 3       : 00000000`78e078e0
Parameter 4       : fffffa80`0c416f10
Caused By Driver  : ndis.sys
Caused By Address : ndis.sys+64100
File Description  : 
Product Name      : 
Company           : 
File Version      : 
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+6f440
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : Z:\media\jlehikoi\Windows7_OS\Windows\Minidump\031517-24570-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 8
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 307 472
Dump File Time    : 15.3.2017 6:50:59
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 031517-15834-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 15.3.2017 6:46:52
Bug Check String  : SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000003b
Parameter 1       : 00000000`c0000005
Parameter 2       : fffff800`03188f41
Parameter 3       : fffff880`07fe2970
Parameter 4       : 00000000`00000000
Caused By Driver  : ntoskrnl.exe
Caused By Address : ntoskrnl.exe+6f440
File Description  : 
Product Name      : 
Company           : 
File Version      : 
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+6f440
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : Z:\media\jlehikoi\Windows7_OS\Windows\Minidump\031517-15834-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 8
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 307 712
Dump File Time    : 15.3.2017 6:48:33
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 030917-27471-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 9.3.2017 20:35:38
Bug Check String  : PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA
Bug Check Code    : 0x00000050
Parameter 1       : fffffa80`0d3a700c
Parameter 2       : 00000000`00000000
Parameter 3       : fffff880`05d44938
Parameter 4       : 00000000`00000000
Caused By Driver  : ntoskrnl.exe
Caused By Address : ntoskrnl.exe+6f440
File Description  : 
Product Name      : 
Company           : 
File Version      : 
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+6f440
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : Z:\media\jlehikoi\Windows7_OS\Windows\Minidump\030917-27471-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 8
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 310 216
Dump File Time    : 9.3.2017 20:37:43
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 030817-24336-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 8.3.2017 15:55:07
Bug Check String  : DRIVER_CORRUPTED_EXPOOL
Bug Check Code    : 0x000000c5
Parameter 1       : 00002069`00002071
Parameter 2       : 00000000`00000002
Parameter 3       : 00000000`00000000
Parameter 4       : fffff800`02fbab05
Caused By Driver  : win32k.sys
Caused By Address : win32k.sys+8de31
File Description  : 
Product Name      : 
Company           : 
File Version      : 
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+6f440
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : Z:\media\jlehikoi\Windows7_OS\Windows\Minidump\030817-24336-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 8
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 307 352
Dump File Time    : 8.3.2017 15:56:24
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 022717-22183-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 27.2.2017 15:35:05
Bug Check String  : SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED
Bug Check Code    : 0x1000007e
Parameter 1       : ffffffff`c0000005
Parameter 2       : fffff800`030099bc
Parameter 3       : fffff880`03f62638
Parameter 4       : fffff880`03f61e90
Caused By Driver  : ntoskrnl.exe
Caused By Address : ntoskrnl.exe+1a89bc
File Description  : 
Product Name      : 
Company           : 
File Version      : 
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+1a89bc
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : Z:\media\jlehikoi\Windows7_OS\Windows\Minidump\022717-22183-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 8
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 307 352
Dump File Time    : 27.2.2017 15:37:02
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 022717-22682-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 26.2.2017 12:47:13
Bug Check String  : DRIVER_CORRUPTED_MMPOOL
Bug Check Code    : 0x000000d0
Parameter 1       : 00000000`00000000
Parameter 2       : 00000000`00000000
Parameter 3       : 00000000`00000000
Parameter 4       : 00000000`00000000
Caused By Driver  : nwifi.sys
Caused By Address : nwifi.sys+3b2e
File Description  : 
Product Name      : 
Company           : 
File Version      : 
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+6f410
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : Z:\media\jlehikoi\Windows7_OS\Windows\Minidump\022717-22682-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 8
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 307 056
Dump File Time    : 27.2.2017 15:34:48
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 022617-22198-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 26.2.2017 0:11:00
Bug Check String  : PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA
Bug Check Code    : 0x00000050
Parameter 1       : fffffa80`0d1ff00c
Parameter 2       : 00000000`00000000
Parameter 3       : fffff880`05f4e938
Parameter 4       : 00000000`00000000
Caused By Driver  : ntoskrnl.exe
Caused By Address : ntoskrnl.exe+6f440
File Description  : 
Product Name      : 
Company           : 
File Version      : 
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+6f440
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : Z:\media\jlehikoi\Windows7_OS\Windows\Minidump\022617-22198-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 8
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 311 520
Dump File Time    : 26.2.2017 12:46:38
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 021217-17690-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 12.2.2017 21:46:31
Bug Check String  : DRIVER_CORRUPTED_MMPOOL
Bug Check Code    : 0x000000d0
Parameter 1       : 00000000`00000000
Parameter 2       : 00000000`00000000
Parameter 3       : 00000000`00000000
Parameter 4       : 00000000`00000000
Caused By Driver  : nwifi.sys
Caused By Address : nwifi.sys+3b2e
File Description  : 
Product Name      : 
Company           : 
File Version      : 
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+6f410
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : Z:\media\jlehikoi\Windows7_OS\Windows\Minidump\021217-17690-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 8
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 307 808
Dump File Time    : 12.2.2017 21:48:01
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 021217-17706-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 12.2.2017 21:43:41
Bug Check String  : BAD_POOL_HEADER
Bug Check Code    : 0x00000019
Parameter 1       : 00000000`00000003
Parameter 2       : fffff800`030668c0
Parameter 3       : 00002069`00002069
Parameter 4       : 00002069`b8e22100
Caused By Driver  : ntoskrnl.exe
Caused By Address : ntoskrnl.exe+6f440
File Description  : 
Product Name      : 
Company           : 
File Version      : 
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+6f440
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : Z:\media\jlehikoi\Windows7_OS\Windows\Minidump\021217-17706-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 8
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 307 712
Dump File Time    : 12.2.2017 21:45:10
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 021217-17487-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 12.2.2017 21:41:26
Bug Check String  : PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA
Bug Check Code    : 0x00000050
Parameter 1       : fffffa80`0ca9c00c
Parameter 2       : 00000000`00000000
Parameter 3       : fffff880`05f35938
Parameter 4       : 00000000`00000000
Caused By Driver  : ntoskrnl.exe
Caused By Address : ntoskrnl.exe+6f440
File Description  : 
Product Name      : 
Company           : 
File Version      : 
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+6f440
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : Z:\media\jlehikoi\Windows7_OS\Windows\Minidump\021217-17487-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 8
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 310 656
Dump File Time    : 12.2.2017 21:42:35
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 021117-25318-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 11.2.2017 11:21:23
Bug Check String  : BAD_POOL_HEADER
Bug Check Code    : 0x00000019
Parameter 1       : 00000000`00000020
Parameter 2       : fffffa80`0c5a0a50
Parameter 3       : fffffa80`0c5a14b0
Parameter 4       : 00000000`0ca60480
Caused By Driver  : nsiproxy.sys
Caused By Address : nsiproxy.sys+2f9b
File Description  : 
Product Name      : 
Company           : 
File Version      : 
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+6f440
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : Z:\media\jlehikoi\Windows7_OS\Windows\Minidump\021117-25318-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 8
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 309 696
Dump File Time    : 11.2.2017 11:23:15
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 011717-25911-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 17.1.2017 14:26:46
Bug Check String  : BAD_POOL_HEADER
Bug Check Code    : 0x00000019
Parameter 1       : 00000000`00000003
Parameter 2       : fffff800`03008c80
Parameter 3       : 2100710a`034120ca
Parameter 4       : 00210f9c`b8e22100
Caused By Driver  : ntoskrnl.exe
Caused By Address : ntoskrnl.exe+6f440
File Description  : 
Product Name      : 
Company           : 
File Version      : 
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+6f440
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : Z:\media\jlehikoi\Windows7_OS\Windows\Minidump\011717-25911-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 8
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 307 736
Dump File Time    : 17.1.2017 14:28:05
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 011517-18345-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 15.1.2017 11:37:28
Bug Check String  : DRIVER_CORRUPTED_MMPOOL
Bug Check Code    : 0x000000d0
Parameter 1       : 00000000`00000000
Parameter 2       : 00000000`00000000
Parameter 3       : 00000000`00000000
Parameter 4       : 00000000`00000000
Caused By Driver  : nwifi.sys
Caused By Address : nwifi.sys+3b2e
File Description  : 
Product Name      : 
Company           : 
File Version      : 
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+6f410
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : Z:\media\jlehikoi\Windows7_OS\Windows\Minidump\011517-18345-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 8
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 307 072
Dump File Time    : 15.1.2017 11:39:07
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 011317-18766-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 13.1.2017 22:56:05
Bug Check String  : SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED
Bug Check Code    : 0x1000007e
Parameter 1       : ffffffff`c0000005
Parameter 2       : fffff800`03007b05
Parameter 3       : fffff880`04362718
Parameter 4       : fffff880`04361f70
Caused By Driver  : rdyboost.sys
Caused By Address : rdyboost.sys+25870
File Description  : 
Product Name      : 
Company           : 
File Version      : 
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+1a8b05
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : Z:\media\jlehikoi\Windows7_OS\Windows\Minidump\011317-18766-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 8
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 307 096
Dump File Time    : 13.1.2017 22:57:14
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 010417-20389-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 4.1.2017 18:14:26
Bug Check String  : PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA
Bug Check Code    : 0x00000050
Parameter 1       : fffffa80`0b74200c
Parameter 2       : 00000000`00000000
Parameter 3       : fffff880`05f29938
Parameter 4       : 00000000`00000000
Caused By Driver  : Ntfs.sys
Caused By Address : Ntfs.sys+ac843
File Description  : 
Product Name      : 
Company           : 
File Version      : 
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+6f440
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : Z:\media\jlehikoi\Windows7_OS\Windows\Minidump\010417-20389-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 8
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 311 832
Dump File Time    : 4.1.2017 18:16:08
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 010417-23088-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 4.1.2017 13:46:01
Bug Check String  : BAD_POOL_HEADER
Bug Check Code    : 0x00000019
Parameter 1       : 00000000`00000003
Parameter 2       : fffff800`0304d760
Parameter 3       : fffff800`0304d760
Parameter 4       : 00002069`00002069
Caused By Driver  : rdyboost.sys
Caused By Address : rdyboost.sys+25d70
File Description  : 
Product Name      : 
Company           : 
File Version      : 
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+6f440
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : Z:\media\jlehikoi\Windows7_OS\Windows\Minidump\010417-23088-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 8
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 307 152
Dump File Time    : 4.1.2017 13:47:50
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 010217-18922-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 2.1.2017 18:53:18
Bug Check String  : PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA
Bug Check Code    : 0x00000050
Parameter 1       : fffffa80`0b99d00c
Parameter 2       : 00000000`00000000
Parameter 3       : fffff880`05d98938
Parameter 4       : 00000000`00000000
Caused By Driver  : 
Caused By Address : 
File Description  : 
Product Name      : 
Company           : 
File Version      : 
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : 
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : Z:\media\jlehikoi\Windows7_OS\Windows\Minidump\010217-18922-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 8
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 262 144
Dump File Time    : 2.1.2017 20:20:17
==================================================
```

Comment: What are the full BSOD error messages? [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) should provide this information. Please [edit] your question to include this.

Comment: I added the dump from BlueScreenView @DavidPostill

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's a driver issue. I've used  a free utility from Nirsoft - BlueScreenView. It scans all minidump files and presents them in a single table that makes identifying the culprit a lot easier.